# How to debounce an async function or prevent it from being invoked a 2nd time before having finished fetching the first query from e.g. a database?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, debouncing, pinia

I'm using pinia store to fetch queries into firestore data base through this action ( async getdayAppointments(appointmentdate)) in the store but some times if the action is triggered two times in a row the result given could be wrong( wrong or the result give is the result for the first query while already 2nd query has been called ) the following is the pinia store callable action to fetch data from the data base

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import {
  collection, onSnapshot, where, query, orderBy,
  addDoc, deleteDoc, doc, updateDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

import { db } from '/src/js/firebase';

export const useStoreAppointments = defineStore('storeAppointments', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      loadingAppointments: false,
      appointments: [],
      transition: '',
      dayAppointments: [],
      selectedDate: today(),
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async getdayAppointments(appointmentdate) {
      this.loadingAppointments = true;
      appointmentsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users', storeAuth.user.id, 'appointments');
      const q = query(appointmentsCollectionRef, where("appointmentdate", "==", appointmentdate));
      onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        const fbAppointments = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const appointment = {
            id: doc.id,
            details: doc.data().details,
            bgcolor: doc.data().bgcolor,
            date: doc.data().appointmentdate,
            duration: doc.data().duration,
            time: doc.data().time,
            title: doc.data().patientname,
            moneypaid: parseInt(doc.data().moneypaid),
            currencypaid: doc.data().currencypaid,
            completed: doc.data().completed,
            doctor: doc.data().doctor,
            start: doc.data().start,
            end: doc.data().end,
            split: doc.data().split,
          };
          fbAppointments.push(appointment);
        }),
        this.appointments = fbAppointments;
        this.loadingAppointments = false;
      });
    },
  },
);
```

so is there a possible trick to prevent 2nd call from being called until first one is finished or always make 2nd call results is to be given if 2 calls is done spontaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

One could write a prototypal wrapper method (maybe named `gate`) which exclusively targets [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction)s.

The async wrapper function which gets returned from the proposed method would prevent the continuous invocation of the original async function (the one the method was called at).

In case a wrapped original async function is still pending, the following example's wrapper would immediately return a protected symbol based value (here `Symbol('ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE')`) which can be accessed via the `Function` type's newly introduced  static constant `ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE`. Thus indicating the repeated invocation of a still pending async function. Only in case the wrapped async function has been settled (either fulfilled or rejected), the async wrapper function does return the value returned by the wrapped original async function.

```js
// another scope than the implementation's module scope.

const { ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE } = Function;

async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/todos');
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  return jsonData;
}

console.log(
  'gated async function name ...',
  createGatedAsyncFunction(fetchData).name, // - using the single function.
  //fetchData.gate().name                   // - using the prototype method.
);
console.log('\n');


// creating the gated variant of an asyn function.

const gatedFetchData = fetchData.gate();                      // - using the prototype method.
//const gatedFetchData = createGatedAsyncFunction(fetchData); // - using the single function.


async function getData() {
  const result = await gatedFetchData();

  if (result === ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE) {
    console.log('closed async invocation gate');
  } else {
    console.log({ result });
  }
}
console.log('... start continuous invocation of `getData` ...');
console.log('\n');

setTimeout(getData, 0);
setTimeout(getData, 50);
setTimeout(getData, 100);
setTimeout(getData, 150);
setTimeout(getData, 200);
setTimeout(getData, 250);

getData();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
//https://gist.github.com/petsel/af63d7f4280d07feb80d6041ab795662#file-asyncfunction-gate-js

const createGatedAsyncFunction =

  // ... poor man's module ...
  (function (Object, Function, Symbol, Reflect) {

    function getInternalTypeSignature(value) {
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).trim();
    }
    function getFunctionSignature(value) {
      return Function.prototype.toString.call(value).trim();
    }

    function getFunctionName(value) {
      return Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(value, 'name').value;
    }
    function getSanitizedTarget(target) {
      return target ?? null;
    }

    function isFunction(value) {
      return (
        'function' === typeof value &&
        'function' === typeof value.call &&
        'function' === typeof value.apply
      );
    }

    function isAsynFunction(value) {
      return (getInternalTypeSignature(value) === '[object AsyncFunction]');
    }
    function isArrowType(value) {
      return (
        isFunction(value) &&
        /^(?:async\s*)?(?:\(.*?\)|[^(),=]+)\s*=>/.test(getFunctionSignature(value))
      );
    }

    // function toTitleCase(value) {
    //   return value.replace(/^\p{Ll}(?=\p{L}+)/gu, match => match.toUpperCase());
    // }

    function createGatedAsyncFunctionExpression(fctName, proceed, sanitizedTarget) {
      let isClosedGate = false;

      return ({
        [ fctName ]: async function (...args) {
          let result = Function.ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE;

          if (!isClosedGate) {
            isClosedGate = true;

            /**
             * - an async gated function's `target` can be delegated at this function's
             *   invocation time, but only if it was not provided already at creation time.
             */
            const context = sanitizedTarget ?? getSanitizedTarget(this);

            result = await proceed.apply(context, args);

            isClosedGate = false;
          }
          return result;
        },
      })[fctName];
    }
    function createGatedAsyncArrowExpression(fctName, proceed) {
      let isClosedGate = false;

      return ({
        [ fctName ]: async (...args) => {
          let result = Function.ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE;

          if (!isClosedGate) {
            isClosedGate = true;

            result = await proceed(...args);

            isClosedGate = false;
          }
          return result;
        },
      })[fctName];
    }

    function createGatedAsyncFunction(proceed, target) {
      // guard.
      if (!isAsynFunction(proceed)) {
        return proceed;
      }
      const isAsyncArrow = isArrowType(proceed);
      const modifiedName = `gated ${ getFunctionName(proceed) }`;
      // const modifiedName = `gated${ toTitleCase( getFunctionName(proceed) ) }`;

      return isAsyncArrow
        && createGatedAsyncArrowExpression(modifiedName, proceed)
        || createGatedAsyncFunctionExpression(modifiedName, proceed, getSanitizedTarget(target));
    }

    function toGate(target) {
      return createGatedAsyncFunction(this, target);
    }

    const closedAsyncInvocationValue = Symbol('ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE');
    const AsyncFunction = (async function() {}).constructor;

    Reflect
      .defineProperty(
        Function,
        'ClOSED_ASYNC_INVOCATION_GATE', {
          get: () => closedAsyncInvocationValue,
        },
      );

    Reflect
      .defineProperty(
        Function,
        'toAsyncGate', {
          value: createGatedAsyncFunction,
        },
      );
    Reflect
      .defineProperty(
        AsyncFunction.prototype,
        'gate', {
          value: toGate,
        }
      );

    return createGatedAsyncFunction;

  }(Object, Function, Symbol, Reflect));
</script>
```

As for the OP's provided example code, one would need to change the latter to ...

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import {
  collection, onSnapshot, where, query, orderBy,
  addDoc, deleteDoc, doc, updateDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

import { db } from '/src/js/firebase';

async function getdayAppointments(appointmentdate) {
  this.loadingAppointments = true;

  const appointmentsCollectionRef =
    collection(db, 'users', storeAuth.user.id, 'appointments');
  const q =
    query(appointmentsCollectionRef, where("appointmentdate", "==", appointmentdate));

  onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot => {
    const fbAppointments = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const appointment = {
        id: doc.id,
        details: doc.data().details,
        bgcolor: doc.data().bgcolor,
        date: doc.data().appointmentdate,
        duration: doc.data().duration,
        time: doc.data().time,
        title: doc.data().patientname,
        moneypaid: parseInt(doc.data().moneypaid),
        currencypaid: doc.data().currencypaid,
        completed: doc.data().completed,
        doctor: doc.data().doctor,
        start: doc.data().start,
        end: doc.data().end,
        split: doc.data().split,
      };
      fbAppointments.push(appointment);
    }),
    this.appointments = fbAppointments;
    this.loadingAppointments = false;
  });
};

export const useStoreAppointments = defineStore('storeAppointments', {
  state: () => ({
    loadingAppointments: false,
    appointments: [],
    transition: '',
    dayAppointments: [],
    selectedDate: today(),
  }),
  actions: {
    // via prototypal method.
    getdayAppointments: getdayAppointments.gate(),

    // via a single function.
    // // getdayAppointments: createGatedAsyncFunction(getdayAppointments),
  },
);
```

... but the question which remains is ... ***"At which point does the OP's async function `getdayAppointments` either `await` a result itself or does return a promise?"***. Thats the entire point of `async...await`.

Comment: i've done that but im getting this error which says it's not a function ( storeAppointments.js?t=1687987871899:64 Uncaught TypeError: getdayAppointments.blocking is not a function
    at storeAppointments.js?t=1687987871899:64:45)

Comment: @omarjasim ... of cause you have to provide the above shown and in detail explained implementation of `AsyncFunction.prototype.blocking` in order to be able of accessing the `blocking` method at any async function. Anyhow, one also could implement `blocking` as a standalone function in case one does not want to augment `AsyncFunction.prototype`.

Comment: but i dunno where to add this implementation? as a js file only in any directory and call it from my pinia store?

Comment: That's what the comment in the above example's implementation suggests ... _"// implementation's module scope."_ ... And of cause one does not need to implement the function `createAsyncBlocking` as prototype method. One easily can implement/rewrite it as function which accepts the to be wrapped function as its sole argument ... `function createAsyncBlocking(proceed) { ... }` and get rid of the current implementation's first line `const proceed = this;` ... One then only has to change the creation of a blocking function to `createAsyncBlocking(myAsyncFct)` instead of `myAsyncFct.blocking()`.

Comment: But still, the last question of my answer remains ... _**"At which point does the OP's async function `getdayAppointments` either await a result itself or does return a promise?"**_ That's the entire point of `async...await`.

Comment: @omarjasim ... I did implement the functionality you were asking for into a _"poor man's module"_, provided as following gist ... [`AsyncFunction.gate.js`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/af63d7f4280d07feb80d6041ab795662#file-asyncfunction-gate-js). I also did change the above executable example code's module-implementation accordingly and adapted its usage.

Comment: @omarjasim ... are there any question left about the `gate`ed implementation and its usage?

Comment: ok i have 2 questions how to implement a variable(which is appointment date) that is sent from the function because my async function is no longer in actions part of the store so i cant use the variable to excute the function on async function getdayAppointments(appointmentdate)

Comment: the other question where should i put the AsyncFunction.gate.js file in the vue JS app and how to call it inside the store ?

Comment: @omarjasim ... I can not follow the 1st of your last two questions. I need to see code or need to be provided with a more detailed problem description in order to provide an adequate answer. As for the last Q ... put the implementation wherever you want into the projects source code. I assume the vue-based project was set up with a proper development environment including all the needed run/test/build processes.

Comment: @omarjasim ... Are you still participating in this thread?